# WordPress Insecure Content

Tags: ssl

The logo is being requested over http rather than https.

I assume this is the code affecting it:

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>
```

any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is more info on the code you are referring to:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

> "https" if is_ssl() and "http" otherwise. If the $scheme argument is "http" or "https" the is_ssl() check is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

The function [**`home_url`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) outputs the home url for your current site.

If you're using a theme with a custom options panel, your theme might be saving the logo option settings with the protocol hard-coded.

Your best bet is to re-select the image in your theme's option panel or through the Wordpress Customizer and save it again.